# When attempting to deploy a business network I get an error 'Failed parsing HTTP/2' in grpc

Tags: hyperledger-composer

The command that was issued was

> composer network deploy -a my-network.bna -i admin -s adminpw

The full error received was

> Error: {"created":"@1495236947.733570390","description":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":2022,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1495236947.733545222","description":"Expected SETTINGS frame as the first frame, got frame type 80","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.c","file_line":479}{"created":"@1495236947.733562422","description":"Trying to connect an http1.x server","file":"../src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.c","file_line":1995,"http_status":400}]}

Command failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is the result of trying to deploy to a Hyperledger Fabric V1 runtime using a Hyperledger Fabric V0.6 profile.
In the above example, no profile was specified which means it will use a default profile and that default profile is specific to Hyperledger Fabric V0.6

It is highly recommended that for all command line interaction that you explicitly specify the profile you want to use, so for example if you have a profile for connecting to your local Hyperledger Fabric V1 runtime called `hlfv1` then you should issue the command

`composer network deploy -p hlfv1 -a my-network.bna -i admin -s adminpw`

(note the -p option to specify the profile to use)